# How to check highest role position of Client (bot)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a ban function and to avoid errors my bot need to check that his highest role is above banned member highest role. I don't know how to check client highest role. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Guild#me`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) returns the member object of your bot in that guild. With that you can just check its role pos.